# Using NSUserDefaults on arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift2, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to use NSUserDefaults to save an array in to my app's core data. I thought it would be good to use NSUserDefaults but the problem is that wherever I put the code that creates the default it throws up the SIGABRT error.

Here is the code that creates the default:

```
let levelArrayDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    levelArrayDefault.setValue(levelsArray, forKey: "levelsArray")
    levelArrayDefault.synchronize()
```

levelsArray is an array of List objects:

```
    class List: NSObject, NSCoding {
    // MARK: Properties
    var name: String
    var AnswersArray = [Answer]()


    init?(name: String) {
        // Initialize stored properties.
        self.name = name

        if name.isEmpty {
            return nil
        }

    }

    required init(coder decoder: NSCoder){
        self.AnswersArray = (decoder.decodeObjectForKey("AA") as? [Answer])!
        self.name = (decoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as? String)!
    }
    func encodeWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
        if let AnswersArray = AnswersArray { coder.encodeObject(AnswersArray, forKey: "AA") }
        if let name = name { coder.encodeObject(name, forKey: "name") }
    }


}
class Answer: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var EnglishAnswer: String = ""
    var ChineseAnswer: String = ""
    init(newEng: String, newChi: String){
        self.EnglishAnswer = newEng
        self.ChineseAnswer = newChi
    }
    required init(coder decoder: NSCoder){
        self.EnglishAnswer = (decoder.decodeObjectForKey("EnglishAnswer") as? String)!
        self.ChineseAnswer = (decoder.decodeObjectForKey("ChineseAnswer") as? String)!
    }
    func encodeWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
        if let EnglishAnswer = EnglishAnswer { coder.encodeObject(EnglishAnswer, forKey: "EnglishAnswer") }
        if let ChineseAnswer = ChineseAnswer { coder.encodeObject(ChineseAnswer, forKey: "ChineseAnswer") }
    }

}
```

How can I stop SIGABRT from popping up and get the array to be stored.
Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: FYI - use `setObject:forKey:`, not `setValue:forKey:`.

Comment: You cannot store a List object or an array of List objects in user defaults. Only property list values are legal.

Comment: Also, you can't store custom classes into NSUserDefaults. You need to use `NSKeyedArchiver` to convert it to `NSData` first. Please search Stack Overflow - there are many existing questions on this topic

Comment: still throwing up sigabrt error

Comment: Post your updated code, and tell us which line is throwing the error, plus copy and paste the exact error.

Comment: All I changed was the set value to set object

Comment: @needshelp take a look at the linked question and if making your class NSCoding compliant doesn't help you saving it to NSUserDefaults please let me know so I can reopen the question

Comment: What linked question?

Comment: The fact is that you can only store property list objects to user defaults. (NSString, NSData, NSDate, NSNumber, NSArray, or NSDictionary objects.) If your array contains anything else, it will fail to save. It shouldn't throws a SIGABRT error, but it won't work.

Comment: @needshelp http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32420335/save-nsarray-of-class-to-cachedirectory

Comment: @needshelp edit your question and update your code

Comment: I already have @LeoDabus

Comment: @needshelp the same principle applies to the Answer class

Comment: Still not working @LeoDabus , Throwing up about 10 errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92614/discussion-between-needshelp-and-leo-dabus).

Comment: encodeWithCoder should be outside init(name: String) { .. }

Comment: It is isn't it? @LeoDabus

Comment: Never mind @LeoDabus

Comment: Now I receive the error of Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String' on the two encodewithcoder lines. @LeoDabus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert it to NSData using NSKeyedArchiver before storing it to NSUserDefaults, try like this:

**update: Xcode 11.4 • Swift 5.2 or later**

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let list = List(name: "Student")
        list.answers = [Answer(english: "english answer", chinese: "中文回答")]
        let data = (try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: [list], requiringSecureCoding: false)) ?? Data()
        UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "listData")
        guard
            let loadedData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "listData"),
            let loadedArray = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(loadedData) as? [List]
            else { return }
        print(loadedData.count)
        print(loadedArray.first ?? "none")
        print(loadedArray.first?.name ?? "no name")
        print(loadedArray.first?.answers.first?.english ?? "no english")
        print(loadedArray.first?.answers.first?.chinese ?? "no chinese")
    }
}
```

---

```
class Answer: NSObject, NSCoding {
    let english: String
    let chinese: String
    init(english: String, chinese: String) {
        self.english = english
        self.chinese = chinese
    }
    required init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        self.english = decoder.decodeString(forKey: "english")
        self.chinese = decoder.decodeString(forKey: "chinese")
    }
    func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(english, forKey: "english")
        coder.encode(chinese, forKey: "chinese")
    }
}
```

---

```
class List: NSObject, NSCoding {
    let name: String
    fileprivate var data = Data()
    var answers: [Answer] {
        get {
            (try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data)) as? [Answer] ?? []
        }
        set {
            data = (try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: newValue, requiringSecureCoding: false)) ?? Data()
        }
    }
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    required init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        self.data = decoder.decodeData(forKey: "answersData")
        self.name = decoder.decodeString(forKey: "name")
    }
    func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(data, forKey: "answersData")
        coder.encode(name, forKey: "name")
    }
}
```

---

```
extension NSCoder {
    func decodeString(forKey key: String) -> String {
        return decodeObject(forKey: key) as? String ?? ""
    }
    func decodeData(forKey key: String) -> Data {
        return decodeObject(forKey: key) as? Data ?? Data()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save your custom object in `NSUserDefaults`, it's not enough to make your class `NSCoding`-compliant -- you have to actually encode the data into an `NSData` object. This is a common mistake -- see [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33111364/643383) for a similar situation.

So, you've added `NSCoding` to your `Answer` and `List` classes. That's a good start. Before you continue, you should verify that you've got that step right by using a `NSKeyedArchiver` to encode an example of a `List` object containing a few `Answer` objects into an instance of `NSData`, and then use `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to decode that data object back into your `List`. Verify that everything that you care about completes the round trip with no problems. This would be an excellent place to use Xcode's testing facility -- you could write a unit test that does exactly what I've described.

Once you know you've got the `NSCoding` stuff right, you should modify your code so that it encodes your `List` as `NSData` and stores the resulting data object in `NSUserDefaults` using the `-setObject:forKey:` method.

Comment: OK. But nobody here can help you if you don't explain the nature of the problems that you're having.