# Swift: Unable to save tuples having more number of records in NSUserDefaults

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, nskeyedarchiver

I am trying to store tuple in NSUserDefaults. My tuple is below.

```
var primaryNumberAndName: [(name:String , number: String, numberType: String, imageProfile: UIImage, imageLogo: UIImage)] = []
```

**Adding datas to tuples**

```
for (var i : Int = 0; i < primaryNameArr.count; i++)
        {
          primaryNumberAndName.append(name: primaryNameArr[i] as! String, 
number: primaryNumberArr[i] as! String,  
numberType: primaryNumberTypeArr[i] as! String, 
imageProfile: UIImage(named: "profile_man.png")!, 
imageLogo: UIImage(named: "Our_Logo.png")!)

        }
```

**Coding:**

```
var dictOfObjectsData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(primaryNumberAndName)
myUserDefaul.setObject(dictOfObjectsData, forKey: "PrimaryContacts")
```

**Error:**

```
Cannot invoke 'archivedDataWithRootObject' with an argument list of type {[(name:String , number: String, numberType: String, imageProfile: UIImage, imageLogo: UIImage)]}
```

Kindly guide me how to solve this.

Comment: You need to convert it to NSData before storing it. You need a class not a tuple

Comment: how to solve this? pls guide me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33192675/using-nsuserdefaults-on-arrays

Answer (score 1):

One option could be to convert `tuple` into `Dictionary` before saving it. Something like this:

```
let primaryNumberKey = "primaryNumber"
let nameKey = "name"

func serializeTuple(tuple: AccessTuple) -> myDictionary {
    return [
        primaryNumberKey : tuple.primaryNumber,
        nameKey : tuple.name
    ]
}

func deserializeDictionary(dictionary: myDictionary) -> myTuple {
    return myTuple (
        dictionary[primaryNumberKey] as String!,
        dictionary[nameKey] as String!
    )
}
```

This is how you can use it:

```
// Writing to defaults
let myConvertedDictionary = serializeTuple(myTuple)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myConvertedDictionary, forKey: "UserDetailslKey")

// Reading from defaults
let myFetchedDictionary = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryForKey("UserDetailslKey") as myDictionary
let myFetchedTuple = deserializeDictionary(myFetchedDictionary)
```

You can now archive Dictionary the regular way!

Comment: Now, If I print my tuples,, It will show 100 records. That I need to store in user defaults. Is it possible with the above code??

Comment: How can I convert all datas in to Dictionary?? I dont know logic in loop. Pls guide me  @Abhinav

Comment: You mean you have a tuple with 100 parameters in it?

Comment: I would advise you to convert array of tuples to array of dictionaries by using the code I shared. Call `serializeTuple` in `for` loop to convert one tuple at a time into dictionary and add it in a new Array. Now, you can save array of dictionaries into `NSUserDefaults`. If you need to know how to do that you can take a look at this [blog](http://www.scriptscoop.net/t/eed05a07a8de/ios-swift-save-array-of-dictionaries-into-nsuserdefaults.html).

Comment: Thr?? Any way to sort the above Tuples?

Comment: Did you try with my above comment?

Comment: That only I am doing. In bw, I have to sort datas. So I asked u.