# How do I save a custom class in swift to NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have made a custom class called test. I made a variable called "game" equal to test. I tried to save "game" to NSUserDefaults and attempted to print values from "game". After running the project I got an error: "Thread 1:signal SIGABRT". How do I save my custom object to NSUserDefaults without getting this error?

Here is my class:

```
class Test {
    var boolean = false
    var int = 1
    var arr = ["one": 1]
}
```

Here is my saving code:

```
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    let game = Test()

    game.arr = ["two": 3]
    game.hi = true
    game.int = 100

    defaults.setObject(game, forKey: "SG")

    let gameSet = defaults.objectForKey("SG")! as! Test

    print(gameSet.int)
    print(gameSet.boolean)
    print(gameSet.arr["one"])
```

This is all in the viewDidLoad method. Excluding the test class.

Comment: You need to make your class NSCoding compliant and use NSKeyedArchiver to convert to NSData before saving to NSUserDefaults or to save it to a plist file

Comment: @leo-dabus, and what if I don't want to use NSObject as a superclass?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33194374/2303865

Comment: Also your `arr` property it is a Dictionary, not an Array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/setObject:forKey:)

> The value parameter can be only property list objects: NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary.

You'll want to look at using `NSKeyedArchiver` instead for custom objects.