# Store Dictionary in NSUserDefaults

Tags: swift, dictionary, nsuserdefaults

So I have a dictionary `var songs = [String: [Song]]()`, where `Song` is a structure with five members.

And i want to store this dictionary like this:           `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(songs, forKey: "Data")`

However, i get an error which says cannot convert to type AnyObject?

Edit:

How would i convert this class `SongManager` to NSCoding so that i can pass it later as NSData to NSUserDefaults?

```
import UIKit

var SongMgr: SongManager = SongManager()

struct song {
    var songnum: Int = 0
    var name = "not defined"
    var lyrics_wo_chords = NSMutableAttributedString()
    var lyrics_w_chords = NSMutableAttributedString()
    var favorite = false
}

class SongManager: NSObject {
    var songs = [String: [song]]()
    func addnewsong(songbook: String, songnum: Int, name: String, lyrics_wo_chords: NSMutableAttributedString, lyrics_w_chords: NSMutableAttributedString, favorite: Bool){

        songs[songbook]?.append(song(songnum: songnum, name: name, lyrics_wo_chords: lyrics_wo_chords, lyrics_w_chords: lyrics_w_chords, favorite: favorite))
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a class with those five properties, make it NSCoding compliant, convert it to data using Keyed archiver and save the data object to NSUserDefaults

Comment: what would be the reverse process if i want to pull the saved data, and save it to the structure again?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33194374/2303865

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using NSUserDefaults on arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33192675/using-nsuserdefaults-on-arrays)

Comment: Also, would it be just easier to use Core Data instead?

Comment: If you know how to use core data just do it

Comment: You need to create a class Song: NSObject, NSCoding

Comment: You can just use `Core Data` create entities for each variable and connect them.

Comment: How many entities will i need to replicate this: `var songs = [String: [song]]()` ? And will it be a to-many relationship between he Dictionary Key and individual Song entity attributes?