# Should I persist pickerViews content in NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, swift

I have in my system a list of countries and a list of states for every country in the world. These content are stored in my database, and I have access to it via a REST request. Countries and states, in thesis, are a static content (I'm not planning to change those registers, but eventually, maybe I will...). For now, I'm doing a GET request every time I need a country, and every time I need a state I'm also doing a GET, using country's ID. My question is: there's some good pattern that cover that kinda of question? Where should I keep countries and states in my system? Should I store it on NSUserDefaults?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a JSON file containing the list of Country name and State name in your application bundle :) As countries and states wont change very frequently its safe to have hardcoded data in your application bundle :)

Lets assume you save your country data in a file called Countries.json

you can read by using,

```
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"countries" ofType:@"json"]];
   NSError *localError = nil;
   NSDictionary *parsedObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&localError];

   if (localError != nil) {
         NSLog(@"%@", [localError userInfo]);
   }
   countriesList = (NSArray *)parsedObject;
```

Thats it :) You have your countrylist with you buddy :)

*OR*

If you dont want to save the country on your own, once you fetch the country list using GET request save the response in a file in your application document folder :)

And next time onwards read data from the same file :)

```
NSString* filePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* fileName = @"countries.json";
NSString* fileAtPath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fileAtPath]) {
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileAtPath];
    NSError *localError = nil;
    NSDictionary *parsedObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&localError];
}
else {
      //make webservice call fetch the country list and write it to file :)
}
```

Saving the entire worlds country list and its capital in user default is not preferrable buddy :) and getting it every time from server will indulge delay to show picker to the user :)

So my suggestion save  a file in application bundle and read it whenever you want the data buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

I not recommend to store those informations on NSUserDefaults, you have not enough to use CoreData but you can archive !

There is a good link if you want to use NSUserDefault anyway:
[Using NSUserDefaults on arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33192675/using-nsuserdefaults-on-arrays)