# Can't decode custom class with NSCoder

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, persistence, nscoding

I have a User `Class` that conforms to `NSCoder` and has properties that are also custom `Classes` that to conform to `NSCoder`.  It successfully (to my knowledge) `encodes` when the app closes as seen below.
AppDelegate Class:

```
    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        saveuser()
    }
```

saveuser():

```
func saveuser() {
    let isSuccessfulSave = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(globUs, toFile: User.archiveURL.path)
    if isSuccessfulSave {
        print("user saved")
    } else {
        print("failed save")
    }
}
```

All of that works just fine, but when I start the app up again, I get to this function in my `User Class`.

```
required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    guard let firstNam = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: coderKey.fName) as? String else {
        print("trouble decoding first name")
        return nil
    }
    guard let lastNam = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: coderKey.lName) as? String else {
        print("trouble decoding last name")
        return nil
    }
    guard let bi = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: coderKey.bio) as? String else {
        print("trouble decoding bio")
        return nil
    }
    guard let tag = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: coderKey.tags) as? [Tag] else {
        print("trouble decoding tags")
        return nil
    }
    guard let organization = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: coderKey.orgs) as? [Organization] else {
        print("trouble decoding orgs")
        return nil
    }
    guard let im = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: coderKey.orgs) as? UIImage else {
        print("trouble decoding img")
        return nil
    }
    self.init(n: firstNam, l: lastNam, b: bi, t: tag, o: organization, i: im)
}
```

it prints

> troubledecoding first name

and exits.  This means that `aDecoder.decodeObject` isn't working.  Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the type of globUs? Are you sure the save was successful?

Comment: `globUs` is of type `User`.  I'm sure that the saving is successful because I have breakpoints all throughout the saving process and the method goes through without a hitch.  Do you know of another way to check?

Comment: Don't post your code in comment. Edit your question and post it there

Comment: UIImage needs to be saved as Data. Tag and Organization arrays too

Comment: Explain what you mean.

Comment: probably not. You will need to post your class implememntation

Comment: you will need to use the same approach I used in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33192675/using-nsuserdefaults-on-arrays/33194374#33194374

Comment: You need to subclass NSObject and make it NSCoding ( not NSCoder) compliant

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/73dsmwh7tu6veid/NSCodingSample.zip?dl=1

Comment: You probably didn't encode properties values in right format. What's in your encode method?